# How to keep line break with NSXMLParser in Objective-c?

Tags: objective-c, json, parsing, xml-parsing, nsxmlparser

I'm parsing a text received in json, and when the function parser of NSXMLParser receive the NSString, sometimes, if the end word is the last word, in the next time join the next word, and it is incorrect, because was independent word.

For example in the text:

> Hi, this is a question about how to parse text with NSXMLParser, I 
>   need solve this.

First the function parser receive a line of text:

> "Hi, this is a question about how to parse text with NSXMLParser, I"

All is correct, this append the text correctly, but then receive this line: "need solve this." And split the text adding next 'I' without a line break:

> "Hi, this is a question about how to parse text with NSXMLParser,
>   **Ineed** solve this."

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
{
  ///Processing the text value of the current element
  NSCharacterSet *characterSet = [NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet];
  NSString *text = [string stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet: characterSet];
  [_selfText appendString:text]; //Here append the string without line break
}
```

This is the function, how can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted is deliberately stripping whitespace (including newlines) from each block of text you get from the parser and your question then asks how to stop this from happening.

Simple. Stop calling `stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet` and you have your solution. Using it in `foundCharacters` is the wrong place for that call. Just append the text in there and do nothing else.

It may be you want to strip whitespace and newlines from the final text value. That's fine. Call `stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet` on the final value of `_selfText` after it has been built completely. This will likely need to be done in the `didEndElement` delegate method.